# Excel macro for selecting only half of the total number of rows in a worksheet

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

I was wondering if someone can help me with this..

I have about 500,000 rows in one excel sheet....and in others I have about 600,000 rows...

So how do I select only half of the rows in the Excel...

What I mean is suppose the total number is 500,000 rows...
then I would like to select only half of it which is 250,000 rows...

And copy that and put it new file and again apply the macro to select half of that i.e 125,000...

Please suggest how to do that.

Comment: have you tried anything? is so, show us what you tried and where you failed and you will get more help.

Comment: no have not tried anything yet...will try something and post back..thanks

Comment: While you're at it, let us know whether you want the first half, last half, random records, etc., and what to do in case the original range has an odd number of rows.

Comment: Actually i have been assigned to work on many worksheet/excel file which has thousands of rows...And I would like to break it down into small pieces so that I can work on small chunks for analysis...Yes the First Half of Rows..so for 500,000 i like to select the first half (i.e 1R- 250,000R )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub CopyHalfRows()
  Dim TargetWorkbook As Workbook
  Dim HalfRows As Range

  On Error GoTo HalfRowsImpossible
    Set HalfRows = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Resize _
      (ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count \ 2)
  On Error GoTo 0
  If Not HalfRows Is Nothing Then
    Set TargetWorkbook = Workbooks.Add
    HalfRows.Copy
    ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial
  End If
  Exit Sub
HalfRowsImpossible:
  MsgBox "Cannot halve worksheet"
  On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

This code

- used `Find` to identify the true first and last used rows in a specific sheet (I used a variable `ws` for the worksheet in case you want to work on a non-active sheet)
- If the sheet is not empty a new range is returned by `rng3` which starts at the first used row, and extends for half the distance between  the first and last rows

  ```
  Sub GetHalfRows()
  Dim ws As Worksheet
  Dim rng1 As Range
  Dim rng2 As Range
  Dim rng3 As Range
  Set ws = ActiveSheet
  Set rng1 = ws.Cells.Find("*", ws.[a1], , , xlByRows, xlPrevious)
  Set rng2 = ws.Cells.Find("*", ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A"), , , xlByRows, xlNext)
  If Not rng1 Is Nothing Then
      Set rng3 = ws.Range(rng2, rng2.Offset((rng1.Row - rng2.Row) / 2, 0)).EntireRow
      MsgBox "selected range is " & rng3.Address
  Else
      MsgBox ws.Name & " is empty"
  End If
  End Sub
  ```

Comment: So we just run this macro..? And it selects the first half of the entire rows? I will try it now...thanks

Comment: a small display screen come "$1R to $250000R selected...then it just goes on and on

Comment: The code returns half of the rows to the range variable 'rng3' then stops, it doesn't go on. You can add further code to copy the range to another book, then repeat the same routine to further halve it etc